# Refresh array in desktop app after actions in web-site

Tags: reactjs, electron, refresh

In the desktop application (written using electron) there is a drop-down list in which, when expanded, the user sees various options to choose from to continue completing the bid (for example, a car). Only for choice!!!

There is also a website (written using react) where the user can not only select a car, but also remove it from the database. But the user can only delete while on the website.

The problem is this: When a user deletes an item on the website, it takes about a minute for the array to be updated in the desktop application.

Question: how can I speed up list updating on a desktop application?

```
 export function CarView() {
  const { data: car } = useCar();

  const carForDisplay = useMemo(() => car, [car]);

  return (
   <>Some view</>
  );
}
```